Running module commands in srun
I run into the same issue as where "module" commands are not accessible from within srun.
SLURM "srun module load" command exits with error
The answer there explains that the simple solution is to run module load outside srun.
However, that is not always so simple if you have a complex cluster management tool that doesn't work that way. Is there a workaround to make module work in srun? (Can I source some file explicitly to make module available?)

You need to pack the module load command and the actual command you need to run inside a single call to Bash like this:
srun [srun options] bash -l -c "module load python && python script.py"

